Why does photodiode junction capacitance affect operating bandwidth? (from a semiconductor physics model perspective)
Here is a typical equivalent circuit diagram of a photodiode.

I feel like this circuit model broadly makes sense to me. You have a diode, in parallel with the junction capacitance. The photocurrent originates within the depletion region by the creation of electron hole pairs (EHP), when the photodiode is illuminated. As the current goes through both the photodiode and capacitance the parallel arrangement of the two to the ideal current source also makes sense to me.
I also get that a parallel capacitance for a voltage signal acts a low impedance for high frequencies and limits bandwidth.
However, we don't actually have a voltage signal, we have a current signal. What I'm confused about is the semiconductor physics when you start thinking about the electron hole pairs and the depletion region. How does the capacitance of the junction affect how the EHP travel through the device, and why would a larger one, affect election hole pairs, being generated/travelling through the junction quickly, for fast changing optical signals?


As you have drawn it the photodiode is not connected to a load and so discharges through its shunt resistance without generating any external current. If you hook it up to a load that can accept that current then the load would be in parallel with the capacitance and so form a RC filter. If you really want to consider the case of a disconnected diode, you will get a very low bandwidth due to the huge RC time constant formed by the shunt resistance, probably orders of magnitude slower then in a practical circuit.

Okay, that makes sense. But then this set of slides, claims that the repsonse time of a photodiode is also limited by the transit time of the carriers, how does the standard equivalent circuit model account for tranist times?  The drift velocity is a function of the junction width and drift velocity of the carriers. The drift velocity is a function of the applied (reverse) bias voltage to the photodiode. And increasing voltage, decreases the junction capacitence, but also increases the junction width, which increases transit times.

https://wp.optics.arizona.edu/kkieu/wp-content/uploads/sites/29/2019/04/Photodetectors-2-04-17-19.pdf

@genericpurpleturtle: because your pulse current has a shape, it's not a delta or a box. The shape can be obtained using Shockley-Ramo's theorem for current induction. Overall, the duration of such shape is dependent on the transit time (which depends on junction width) and so it further limits overall system BW. Both effects are present, so you need the convolution of the filter response with pulse response.
